# Python "Memory Leak" when using threading and sqlite3

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite, memory, memory-leaks

I'm using sqlite3 and threading for a project I have and It's brought me a lot of problems. I managed to solve all of them after getting a better understanding of sqlite3 but I have not managed to solve a memory leak. I have no idea if it's the threading or sqlite3 or **both** causing it. I think it's a combination of both. I have finally managed to create a minimal example to show you:

```
import sqlite3
import threading
import random
import gc
import time

from collections import Counter
import linecache
import os
import tracemalloc

def display_top(snapshot, key_type='lineno', limit=10):
    snapshot = snapshot.filter_traces((
        tracemalloc.Filter(False, "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>"),
        tracemalloc.Filter(False, "<unknown>"),
    ))
    top_stats = snapshot.statistics(key_type)

    print("Top %s lines" % limit)
    for index, stat in enumerate(top_stats[:limit], 1):
        frame = stat.traceback[0]
        # replace "/path/to/module/file.py" with "module/file.py"
        filename = os.sep.join(frame.filename.split(os.sep)[-2:])
        print("#%s: %s:%s: %.1f KiB"
              % (index, filename, frame.lineno, stat.size / 1024))
        line = linecache.getline(frame.filename, frame.lineno).strip()
        if line:
            print('    %s' % line)

    other = top_stats[limit:]
    if other:
        size = sum(stat.size for stat in other)
        print("%s other: %.1f KiB" % (len(other), size / 1024))
    total = sum(stat.size for stat in top_stats)
    print("Total allocated size: %.1f KiB" % (total / 1024))

connection = sqlite3.connect("testdatabase.db", check_same_thread=False)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM test_table;",);

# This has to be enabled first time running to create the table
# cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE test_table(val1 TEXT, val2 TEXT, val3 TEXT, val4 TEXT, val5 TEXT)")

critical_lock_sqlite = threading.Lock()

def mem_tester(value1,value2,value3,value4,value5):
    try:
        critical_lock_sqlite.acquire(True)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        if cursor.execute("SELECT val2, val3 FROM test_table WHERE val2=? AND val3=?",
                          (value2, value3)).fetchone():
            del value1, value2, value3, value4, value5
            state_int = 0
        elif not cursor.execute("SELECT val2, val3 FROM test_table WHERE val2=? OR val3=?",
                                (value2, value3)).fetchone():
            state_int = 2
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                           (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5))
            connection.commit()
        elif cursor.execute("SELECT val3 FROM test_table WHERE val3=?", (value3,)).fetchone():
            state_int = 1
            cursor.execute("UPDATE test_table SET val2=? WHERE val3=?", (value2, value3))
        elif not cursor.execute("SELECT val2, val3 FROM test_table WHERE val2=? AND val3=?",
                                (value2, value3)).fetchone():
            state_int = 2
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                           (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5))
            connection.commit()
        # Unexpected Occurrance
        else:
            state_int = 2
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                           (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5))
            connection.commit()
        cursor.close()
        del cursor
    finally:
        critical_lock_sqlite.release()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tracemalloc.start()
    for i in range(1, 10000):
        threading.Thread(target=mem_tester, args=("test",random.randint(1, 999),''.join(random.choice("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890") for _ in range(8)),"random","random")).start()
    gc.collect()
    time.sleep(5)
snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
display_top(snapshot)
```

I'm having a hard time finding the problem here. The memory keeps going up and if I remove the critical_lock_sqlite, it won't go up as much but then I will have a million errors because I am not allowed to run the commands at the same time in different threads. Is anyone able to help me with this case?
Note that this script will also show where the most memory is used. In this case it shows mostly that threading is using.
Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you keep a track of all `10000` threads and `.join()` them after the `sleep()`, but before `tracemalloc.take_snapshot()`? That's a lot of threads.

Comment: I know that It's a lot of threads, but that's just to make it easier to show how the memory keeps increasing. In my "main" project, the case is not exactly the same. There I use requests-future to scrape a simple site and then I append some information there. There is "only" 12 threads there. Using .join and keeping track of the threads doesn't help. The memory somehow keeps increasing but it gets freed when stopping the program stops as it should. But in the main project, the script should not stop, so the memory would keep on increasing until it is full. Thank you

Comment: I think I'm asking: What is `tracemalloc` measuring? It seems to be measuring the space taken up by the threads. You could eliminate that by creating the threads first, taking a snapshot, running the threads to completion, taking a second snapshot and comparing them. You could also eliminate the threads entirely, for comparison, by just running `mem_tester` 10000 times since it is already single threaded due to the `Lock()`.

Comment: Is `critical_lock_sqlite` a `Lock` instance? or is it something that behaves like a `Lock`? If so, then your 10,000 threads will be forced to execute the body of the `mem_tester()` one-by-one. What happens if you don't create any threads, but simply _call_ the function 10,000 times in a loop?

Comment: Last time I tried, it worked fine if I removed both threading and the lock. But I need the lock and threading since in my main project I do other stuff aswell that I use threading for. If I would have only what I have in the example, I would have been able to go without threading. I have tried using multiprocessing now, which works without any memory leak.

Comment: Re, "...But I need the lock and threading..." Sure, but if the function can only be executed by one thread at a time, then there is no reason to create more than one thread to run it.

Comment: I think you are missunderstanding me. In my "main project" I have quite a lot more in the function that gets executed at the same time which would have taken a lot longer to do without threading. But in a part of that function, the threads wait to be able to use the database.